# How to break kotlin when clause?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, switch-statement, break

Suppose that I have code in Java

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                if (something()) {
                     break;
                }
                // do more stuff here
                break;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I rewrote it for something like this, but I'm not sure it's correct and it doesn't have any flaws.

```
override fun onTouch(view: View, motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    when (motionEvent.actionMasked) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                if (something()) {
                    return false
                }
                // do more stuff here
            }
    }
    return false
}
```

What is the best way to emulate/implement in kotlin `break` like in the java switch statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kotlin `when` expressions are very different from Java `switch` expressions in terms of execution. In Java, a switch call will try to run the next available case if you don't break. In Kotlin as soon as the first condition is met, the `when` call automatically breaks so you don't really need a `break` statement inside a Kotlin `when` expression.

Comment: Another way to put it is that Kotlin `when` has no fall-through behavior. Breaking is automatic.

Comment: So the best way to reproduce java behaviour in the middle of `case` block is to use `return` in kotlin?

Comment: Assuming you always return false, I personally would use if/else instead of returning from inside the `when` block, because I think it's cleaner to use an all-or-nothing approach if possible. If some of your branches of logic return true, I would put `return` before the `when` and make sure all branches end in a return value.